# Switch hover effect to link when on mobile device or small display

Tags: html, css, hover

I have a website where I use the hover effects over items to show more details. When on small displays or mobile device I would like to "convert" the hover effect to a link and show a modal panel with informations.
I found this solution

```
<h2>
    <span class="profile-large">Item name</span>
    <a class="profile-small" href="javascript:;">Item name</a>
</h2>
```

So, in css file I define breakpoint in order to render visible the profile-large class or profile-small class.
Is this a valid and correct approach?
Thanks

Comment: Why not? It doesn't break any rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes,

that's a common approach.

Look how the bootstrap Front End framework handles this https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/responsive-utilities/. Also with the help of utility CSS classes.

Here you can find the code for that: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass/blob/master/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/_responsive-utilities.scss

Of course you could develop your own solution based on that. Especially if you don't need all of them to save some bytes.

Comment: Thank you so much! I was worried about putting redundancy in the code. This is the same approach for long text? That is, if I have a long text that I see in full on the desktop, on mobile I would like to see only a part of it and then add "read more".
Thanks

Comment: i guess you could build that component with the help of that utility. but it will be cleaner / more readable with a JS only solution.

Answer (score 2):

You will have to work with @media rules.

I will take 900px for max width for a mobile device and everything above for a desktop device in my below example.

**CSS**

```
@media (min-width: 901px) { // desktop-devices
    .profile-small { display: none; }
}

@media (max-width: 900px) { // mobile devices
    .profile-large { display: none; }
}
```

Basically you say, hide the `anchor` for larger screens and hide the `span` for smaller screens.

Comment: I'm sorry, a link can be active or not active based on @media rules? Thanks

Comment: @robyg72 In my example you remove the complete anchor (class `profile-small`) on mobile screens.